# Crankcase And Kickstarter are cracking

Tags: cracking

I have a 09  Honda crf50f and every 4 to 5 kicks it makes this awful crack noise and the kick starter won’t move unless you let go and it keeps doing this and the bike won’t start but it also has carb problems so idk if it’s the crank that won’t let it start or the carb probably both does anyone know what’s wrong plz help.